# Item description not visible in sales email

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3

I'm trying to print the description for each product in the items table of the sales email.

Based on the file, it looks like it should be doing this already:

In `module-sale/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml` we have this line:

`<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>`

Is there any reason this wouldn't be rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may change the line

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
```

with

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getProduct()->getDescription()) ?>
```

Comment: Success! What, then, is the purpose of the line as it is?

Comment: Item has getSku, getName as obvious getters for sale item. But if you want more, you have to get it through item->getProduct

Comment: That makes sense, just wondering why `$_item->getDescription()` was included in the code? If it serves some purpose in a certain context?

Comment: Doubt it, short description possibly but description is meant to big very long, isn’t it?

Comment: Yeah, who knows. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you appreciate, good to create a community of like minded people